# How can I use a diagonal line as a boundary?

Tags: python, pygame, computational-geometry, lines

Maybe I'm having a brainfart, it seems like this should be really simple. I've drawn a line in python using pygame:

```
pygame.draw.line(screen, color, e.start, e.stop, 3)
```

This draws a line on the object screen in the color color, from the tuple coordinates `e.start` to the tuple coordinates `e.stop`.

Anyway, I'm trying to create a game which stops an object when it hits any part of the line. I had a few ideas, most of them computationally expensive. Is there a simple straightforward way to solve this problem, or should I make the processor into a grunt?

Comment: Is your object boundary defined by a polygon?

Comment: No, the boundary is simply a line, though I could create a polygon behind it if that helps.
I created an 'edge' object which contains the coordinates for the line and is represented as 'e' in that line of code up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh duh!  The equation of a line.  y=mx+b can be derived from 2 points.  My goodness.  Then I can just use the size of the object I want to stop on the line to check it it's hitting the line.